# How to make LightDM login screen have the same background as the desktop background in Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: 22.04, lightdm, mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE 22.04.

Back when Ubuntu used Unity, the background of the LightDM login screen automatically changed when a different desktop background was selected.

Can something like that done in Ubuntu MATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATE 22.04 uses `arctica-greeter` as default theme. It has a dconf option to draw user backgrounds, which however does not work due to bug.

I tried the script at this post, the 18.04 script works in my case along with slick greeter theme:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/lightdm-doesnt-show-the-user-background/11254/

First switch to `slick-greeter` (it has a quite similar layout) and use its configure option to enable `Draw user backgrounds`.

1. install slick-greeter via command: `sudo apt install slick-greeter`
2. Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and enable the new greeter via `greeter-session=slick-greeter`
3. open `Control Center` -> `Login Window`, set a background and enable `Draw user background`.
4. Finally, create a script (*use the one for 18.04 or just download & install the .deb*) and make it auto-start. See: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/lightdm-doesnt-show-the-user-background/11254/23
5. Restart computer.

via: https://fostips.com/change-login-background-ubuntu-mate/